# Initialization required before assigning element value?

Tags: function, matlab, variables, indexing

'' Unrecognized function or variable 'dy'.

Error in functiondy ''

Is it because the codes did not say anything about dy before assigning value to dy(1) and dy(2)?

how do i fix this?

```
function dy=functiondy(t,y)

global example

if (example==1)

dy(1)=-pi*cos(pi*y(2));
dy(2)=pi*sin(t*y(1));

elseif (example==101)

tmp=(y(1)^2+y(2)^2)^0.5;
dy(1)=(y(2)-y(1))/tmp;
dy(2)=y(1)*y(2)/tmp;

end
dy=dy';                 % error line
end
```

Comment: The problem is that if `example` is neither 1 nor 101, `dy` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You can say `dy(1) = ...` without saying `dy = ...` first, and `dy` will just automatically pop in to existence.

Looks like the problem is that `example` is neither 1 nor 101, so both your `if` blocks are bypassed. So it gets to this line:

```matlab
dy=dy';
```

and here, there's a `dy` on the *right* side of the "=", so you're trying to read it before ever assigning it.

Add a catchall `else` block to your `if`, or initialize `dy` with a default value before the `if` block starts.